# Rails select_tag with ajax action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms

I have the following select list.

```
<%= select_tag(:editlevel,options_from_collection_for_select(Level.all, :id, :name)) %>
```

When the user selects an option from the above list, the list below should be populated with values from database based on the above selection.

```
<%= select_tag(:lques,{},{ :size =>10, :style => "width:200px"}) %>
```

I think i should make use of a remote_function with the onchange event. But i have no idea on how to use it and populate the latter list the values from the database. Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way that I solved this was:

```
<select id="editlevel" name="editlevel" onchange="
   <%= remote_function(
           :update => 'lques', 
           :url => {:action => :lques}, 
           :with => "'level=' + $('editlevel').value %>
">

</select>

<select id="lques" name="lques">
</select>
```

Then your lques action can just get what lques records you need and do a `options_for_select` and it should just put what comes back from the server as `$('lques').innerHTML`

**This is air code, and it has not been tested.**

Comment: As a note, try and not use onchange and make the page use unobtrusive javascript when you must use javascript.

There are plenty of examples on line where you could do something like:

  input.onchange = function() {
    populateFields();
  }

It makes the HTML cleaner to read when you get back to it and will give you the opportunity to DRY up your views should you need the same functionality again.